# Django {% if custom_template_tag > 0 %} does not work

Tags: django, django-templates

i've got these template tags

```
@register.assignment_tag
def test1():
    return 2

@register.simple_tag
def test2():
    return 2
```

In my template i've got this

```
{% test1 as test1_var %}    
{% if test1_var > 0 %}Test1{% endif %}

{% if test2 > 0 %}Test2{% endif %}
```

results in
    Test1

What i want is a template tag which only appears if it is greater than 0, but i cannot believe that the assignment_tag is the right solution for that. Why does Test2 not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test2` inside that `if` statement does not actually call a template tag; it can only refer to a (non-existent) context variable. That's why the assignment tag works, because you do actually set such a variable.

If you don't like the assignment tag, you might consider doing the whole comparison inside the tag, so that it outputs the Test1/Test2 value directly.

Comment: ok thanks, thought i am doing something wrong using the assignment tag